# Eliminate all rows except highest value, by subject

Tags: subset

Data: I have data in a dataframe, with column headings "subject_id", "date" and "categorical_value1". Categorical_value1 may have values A, B and C. Each subject ID has multiple rows, but they are not sorted in any particular order.

Question: I would like to create a subset of the data in which categorical_value1 must be = A, and in which only the latest (most recent) date value is selected, for each subject_id. So there will be at most one unique row per subject_id, but possibly no rows for a given subject_id if that id does not have a categorical_value1 = A. Any advice about the most economical way to do this?

Comment: Can you structure your text a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1.subject_id, c1.date, c1.categorical_value1
from Category c1
where c1.categorical_value1 = 'A'
inner join 
select c2.subject_id, max(c2.date) as date, c2.categorical_value1
from Category c2
where c2.categorical_value1 = 'A'
group by c2.subject_id, c2.categorical_value1
on c1.subject_id = c2.subject_id
and c1.date = c2.date
```

Comment: So far not sure how to use suggestion. Example of my problem: 
set.seed(1234)
mydates <- as.Date(sample(c("2007-06-22", "2004-02-13", "2004-03-29", "2001-10-10", "2008-05-05", "2007-03-04"), 10, replace = TRUE))
myids <- sample(c('a001', 'a002', 'a003'), 10, replace = TRUE)
mycatvar <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 10, replace = TRUE)
mydf <- data.frame(myids, mydates, mycatvar) 

Solution should give 

a001 3/4/07 A
a002 10/10/01 A
a003 6/22/07 A